# How to convert Local time to am/pm time format using JodaTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm very new to Joda api and I have the call like this:

```
 LocalTime time = new LocalTime("13");
```

it prints as:`13:00:00.000`.

I wish I could display it like this: `1:00 PM`.

How I can achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734452/display-current-time-in-12-hour-format-with-am-pm

Comment: @theMarceloR not a duplicate. The one you linked to is using `SimpleDateFormat` while @batman is asking about JodaTime

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected, here's my upvote to @batman. BTW, I'm a huge fan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter builder = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm:ss.SSa");
```

Comment: its throwing me an error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "09:00:00.000" is malformed at "0" for new LocalTime("9"), when I call builder.parseLocalTime(time.toString())

Comment: @batman Why do you want to parse now? In your question you speak about formatting/printing, and this answer is sufficient for that purpose. If you want to parse a string in another format then you need another pattern, of course.

Comment: @StackFlowed I dislike the "holier than thou, gatekeepers of knowledge" attitude. There's a difference btwn documentation and knowledge. That's why classes are taught with both teachers and books.

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

```
    LocalTime time = new LocalTime("13");    
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm a");
    String str = fmt.print(time);
```

And got this output for str:

```
"1:00 PM"
```

Comment: Giving me error like this its throwing me an error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "09:00:00.000" is malformed at "0" for new LocalTime("9"), when I call builder.parseLocalTime(time.toString())