# time conversion in java for 12:00 noon

Tags: java

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class ConvertDatesBetweenFormatsWithSimpleDateFormat {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
     String dateStr = "12:30";

        DateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        Date date = srcDf.parse(dateStr);
        DateFormat destDf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
         dateStr = destDf.format(date);
        System.out.println("Converted date is : " + dateStr);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to convert date format from hh:mm to HH:mm:ss. While this code is working fine for all the time, its not givig the required result for time between 12-1. Eg:  for 12:30 its giving 00:30(it should be 12:30 instead), while for 1:30 it is giving as 13:30.
What changes should be done in this case?

Comment: try 'HH:mm a' instead of 'hh:mm'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display current time in 12 hour format with AM/PM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734452/display-current-time-in-12-hour-format-with-am-pm)

Comment: You do not use the `a` pattern for the AM/PM marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want second also then use below code but second is not getting from given format that's why it will be alway 00.

Result:-
Converted date is : 12:30:00 AM

```
DateFormat destDf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the AM PM marker in the parser

```
 DateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
```

And specify the AM PM in the given date string

```
 String dateStr = "12:30 PM";
```

Otherwise java can't simply know if hte hour is AM or PM.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat simply does parsing on the input String.
**It doesn't do any implicit conversion**.
Its like populating Date object fields with parsed values of input String.

Refer below link for possible Date patterns
http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/how-to-convert-string-to-24-hour-date-time-format-in-java/

Comment: In addition to any link, you should describe all important notes from the link.

Comment: Sure , Let me know if you need any inputs