# Android date format

Tags: java, android, time, format

I don't understand how work java SimpleDateFormat. I want to show date and time by Locale.

**For example**

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
DateFormat correctDateFormatter =SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
correctDateFormatter.format(date);
```

So I wait to output in 24-h format like

> 23:00

but I get it like

> 11 PM

How I can show time and date depends on the Local and do no not use time pattern("hh:mm" and so on)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734471/8089931

Comment: Please see my answer to display Locale based time

Comment: please look my question again

Comment: If you just call `getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT)`, it'll use the specific format for the device's default locale. Is that what you need?

Comment: Even on Android it’s certainly worth considering skipping the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class and using the modern Java date and time API instead. This comes for Android in the ThreeTenABP library project, see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. When I run your code on my Java 8, I get `23:00` as you said you had expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CheckDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date date = new Date();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
        SimpleDateFormat correctDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.FRANCE);
        correctDateFormatter.format(date);
        System.out.println("24 hrs format :: "+correctDateFormatter.format(date));
    }

}
```

Otherwise if you change your system date as 24hrs format it will come in program also

Answer (score 1):

This will return the format you specified in the timezone you need:

```
String timeString = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.FRANCE).format(date);
```

Comment: i want to use SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance with style

Comment: In that case i don't think what you want is possible. Styles seem to be pre defined. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html

Comment: ok, how i can to set correct time pattern depends on the local? i want to show am:pm in usa and without in europe

Comment: I would try to use Locale.FRANCE instead of Locale.getDefault(). The default timezone on the device seem to be US Locale.

Comment: but i do not know where run my app

Comment: I just want to make sure Locale.getDefault() is not returning US Locale for you, even if you are expecting Locale.FRANCE.

Comment: What you are trying is correct, but it seems like the pre-defined format for SimpleDateFormat.SHORT in Locale.FRANCE is 11 PM.

Comment: well, to solve this problem i need to know current location and according to it build time pattern. i have no option?

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.FRANCE);
```

**H** is used for 24 hour and  **h** 12 hour format.

Answer (score 1):

Try **`String formattedLocalTime = getFormattedLocalTimeFromUtc("2016-02-16T04:46:28Z", "MM/dd/yyyy");`**

```
final String LOCAL_TIME_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"; //This is your local date format
final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"; //This is input date format
final String TIMEZONE_UTC = "UTC";

public static String getFormattedLocalTimeFromUtc(String utcTimeStamp, String outputFormat) {

    String formattedTime = null;
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(utcTimeStamp)) {

            String localTime = null;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIMEZONE_UTC));
            try {
                localTime = sdf.parse(utcTimeStamp).toString();
            }
            catch(ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(LOCAL_TIME_FORMAT);
            inputDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIMEZONE_UTC));
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = inputDateFormat.parse(localTime);
            }
            catch(ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat);
            formattedTime = outputDateFormat.format(date);
        }
    }
    return formattedTime;
}
```

**`HH.mm`** format for time

> H: Hour in day (0-23)
>   h: Hour in am/pm (0-11)

Comment: please look my question again

Comment: You want to display time according to your Locale, right?

Comment: That's what I have put in my answer, 
You can Replace Locale.getDefault() with your Locale, Also mention timeZone

Comment: TimeZone.getDefault()

Comment: no it isn't! in your answer i need to use "HH:mm" and what about usa? in usa i want to show "hh:mm" so i need to know which pattern to use

Comment: First of all, your question is not clear. Secondly I have mentioned LOCAL_TIME_FORMAT and other fields, change it according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Check the SDF documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Where there are various types of characters you can use to format your date,

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.FRANCE);
```

Once you have this:

```
simpledateFormat.format(date);
```