# I need to show time 24 hrs format to 12 (am/pm) hrs format

Tags: java, android

In this code show wrong time in case of 12:01:00 it shows 12:00 AM but right time is 12:00 PM:

```
private static final String sourceFormat = "hh:mm:ss";
private static final String targetFormat = "hh:mm a";

public static String convertTimeFormat(String dateStr) {

    if (dateStr.equals("")) {
        return "";
    }
    Log.d("date", dateStr + "---" + sourceFormat + "---" + targetFormat);
    SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceFormat);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = form.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat(targetFormat);
    String newDateStr = postFormater.format(date);
    Log.d("Lead Response", newDateStr);
    return newDateStr;
}
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734452/display-current-time-in-12-hour-format-with-am-pm

Comment: You need to use 'HH' instead of 'hh' in sourceFormat if your source time in 24 hours format.

Comment: @HareshChhelana it is not working

Comment: @AkshayBarodia if it's not working then why you accept Venki WAR answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static final String sourceFormat = "hh:mm:ss";
```

change to

```
private static final String sourceFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
```

It's working I checked in My IDE

```
private static final String sourceFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
    private static final String targetFormat = "hh:mm a";

public static String convertTimeFormat(String dateStr)  {

        if (dateStr.equals("")) {
            return "";
        }
        Log.d("date", dateStr + "---" + sourceFormat + "---" + targetFormat);

        **SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceFormat, Locale.US);**


        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = form.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        **SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat(targetFormat, Locale.US);**

        String newDateStr = postFormater.format(date);
       Log.d("Lead Response", newDateStr);
        return newDateStr;
    }
```

Comment: That is what I was suggested in my comment.

Comment: i did n't see your comment.When i'm starting solution no comments on there

Comment: Sorry. if you feel wrong

Comment: It's okay, I just try to highlight that comment thanks and good work.